# catalan numbers - counting sequances with sum of 0

Tags: catalan-numbers

I need help in prooving that the cardinal number of the following set is $C_{n}$:

The set of all sequences

$a_{1}, a_{2}, .., a_{n} \in \mathbb{Z} \\ s.t \\ a_{1}+a_{2}+....+a_{n} = 0$

and for every $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$ , $ a_{i}\geq -1$ and $a_{1}+a_{2}+....+a_{i}\geq 0$

For example, if $n =3$:

the series in the set will be:
$(0, 0, 0),(0, 1, −1),(1, 0, −1),(1, −1, 0),(2, −1, −1)$

**EDIT:**
I thought of presenting the problem using parenthesis. Every sequence as a total equal number of "(" and ")". Every sub-sequence has more "(" than ")".

$0$ is presented by "$\color{blue}(\color{blue})$",

$1$ by "$\color{red}($"

$-1$ by "$\color{green})$"

The problem is that the number of parentheses isn't fixed for a given $n$. For example when $n=2$ the series could be $\color{blue}(\color{blue})\color{blue}(\color{blue})$ or $\color{red}(\color{green})$

Also, I don't know how to "translate" the term $ a_{i}\geq -1$

And for $n=3$ the representation of the sequences $(0,1,-1)$ and $(1,-1,0)$ is the same - "$()()$"

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wholly revised; my original idea cannot easily be patched.**

$C_n$ is the number of ordered trees with $n+1$ vertices. There is a bijection between these and your sequences of length $n$ as follows. Do a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (or preorder search, if that terminology is more familiar) through the tree. When each node except the last is first encountered, write down the integer that is $1$ less than the number of children of that node. Ignore the last node.

For $n=3$, for instance, we have the following $C_3=5$ trees with their associated sequences:

```
     *         *          *          *         *
     |        / \        / \         |        /|\
     *       *   *      *   *        *       * * *
     |           |      |           / \
     *           *      *          *   *
     |
     *
   0,0,0     1,-1,0     1,0,-1     0,1,-1   2,-1,-1
```

The inverse function is a bit harder to describe but not hard to illustrate. Say we have the sequence $2,1,-1,-1,-1$ for $n=6$; we can build the corresponding tree starting at the top. The root will have $3$ children. The traversal goes next to the first child, which must have $2$ children. Its first child has none, so it’s a leaf. Its second child is another leaf. And the traversal then goes to the root’s second child, which is a leaf. This of course leaves the root’s last child to be a leaf as well, and we have this tree:

```
             *
            /|\
           * * *
          / \
         *   *
```

If you’ve not already seen the fact that $C_n$ is the number of ordered trees with $n+1$ vertices, there is a fairly easy bijection between these trees and balanced parenthesis strings. Do a complete depth-first traversal of the tree, starting and ending at the root, and record a left parenthesis when you go down an edge (i.e., away from the root) and a right parenthesis when you go up an edge. The five trees with $4$ nodes shown in the first diagram correspond in order to the strings ((())), ()(()), (())(), (()()), and ()()(); the tree with $6$ nodes shown above yields the string (()())()().

**Added:** Combining these bijections yields a direct bijection from your sequences to balanced parenthesis strings that isn’t *too* hard to describe. Given the sequence $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle$, begin by writing down a row of $a_1+1$ matched pairs of parentheses and call the first pair the *focal pair*. Using the sequence $$\langle 3,0,-1,0,1,-1,-1,0,-1\rangle$$ as an example, I start with

$$\color{red}{()}()()()\;,$$

where the focal pair is red. Suppose that you’ve processed $a_k$ for some $k<n$. If $a_{k+1}\ge 0$, place a row of $a_{k+1}+1$ matched pairs of parentheses in the current focal pair and make the first of these pairs the new focal pair; in my example this results in the string

$$(\color{red}{()})()()()\;,$$

where the focal pair is again shown in red. If $a_{k+1}=-1$, however, as is now the case in my example, write nothing and shift the focus to the first empty matched pair to the right:

$$(())\color{red}{()}()()\;.$$

Continue in this fashion to complete the construction of the associated parenthesis string:

$$\begin{align*}
a_4=0:&\quad(())(\color{red}{()})()()\\
a_5=1:&\quad(())((\color{red}{()}()))()()\\
a_6=-1:&\quad(())((()\color{red}{()}))()()\\
a_7=-1:&\quad(())((()()))\color{red}{()}()\\
a_8=0:&\quad(())((()()))(\color{red}{()})()\\
a_9=-1:&\quad(())((()()))(())\color{red}{()}
\end{align*}$$

This is what I was fumbling towards in my original answer. The associated tree:

```
                    ----------*----------
                    |        / \        |
                    |       /   \       |
                    *      *     *      *
                    |      |     |
                    |      |     |
                    *      *     *
                          / \
                         /   \
                        *     *
```

Comment: Thank. I edited my question thank to your idea. I don't really understand why you start each sequence with a "(", and how did you come up with those "signs" for the numbers. Also, your representation for all of the positive numbers is the same - so what if you have a sequence (2,3,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1) and (3,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)  for n=7? How would you make sure the representation is different for the two?

Comment: @ical: You’re right about the suggested map not being injective; I’ve completely revised the answer.